# In SQL how to show values of two rows and ratio of the values of those two rows?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a query (in MySQL, but this is a general SQL question) that looks like this:

```
SELECT 'Hits', variable_value 
FROM global_status 
WHERE variable_name = 'QCACHE_HITS'

UNION

SELECT 'Inserts', variable_value 
FROM global_status 
WHERE variable_name = 'QCACHE_INSERTS';
```

It produces the following result:

```
+---------+----------------+
| Hits    | variable_value |
+---------+----------------+
| Hits    | 8330           |
| Inserts | 7075           |
+---------+----------------+
```

What I'm trying to get to is a ratio of those two, which are in the same SQL. Basically a result set to look like this:

```
+---------+----------------+
| Hits    | variable_value |
+---------+----------------+
| Hits    | 8330           |
| Inserts | 7075           |
| H/I     | 1.177
+---------+----------------+
```

How to compose this SQL? I think a JOIN might be needed, but I am not sure how to get the *value* of two rows for the math involved in the SQL. Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've assumed your given code is working to give this answer.

```
SELECT 'Hits', variable_value 
FROM global_status 
WHERE variable_name = 'QCACHE_HITS'
UNION
SELECT 'Inserts', variable_value 
FROM global_status 
WHERE variable_name = 'QCACHE_INSERTS'
UNION
SELECT 'H/I', (
(SELECT variable_value FROM global_status WHERE variable_name='QCACHE_HITS')
/
(SELECT variable_value FROM global_status WHERE variable_name = 'QCACHE_INSERTS')
) AS 'variable_value';
```

Comment in case of not working. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. It works! I quite like the idea below from G Linoff about making these into columns, but yours is more precise to the specific question asked. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you can accept these as three separate *columns* rather than *rows*, you can do:

```
select max(case when variable_name = 'QCACHE_HITS' then variable_value end) as hits,
       max(case when variable_name = 'QCACHE_INSERTS' then variable_value end) as inserts,
       (max(case when variable_name = 'QCACHE_HITS' then variable_value end) /,
        max(case when variable_name = 'QCACHE_INSERTS' then variable_value end)
       ) as ratio
from global_status ;
```

It might even be simplest to unpivot this:

```
select h.hits,
       (case when h.hits = 'hits' then hits
             when h.hits = 'inserts' then inserts
             else ratio
        end) 
from (select max(case when variable_name = 'QCACHE_HITS' then variable_value end) as hits,
             max(case when variable_name = 'QCACHE_INSERTS' then variable_value end) as inserts,
             (max(case when variable_name = 'QCACHE_HITS' then variable_value end) /,
              max(case when variable_name = 'QCACHE_INSERTS' then variable_value end)
             ) as ratio
      from global_status
     ) s cross join
     (select 'hits' as hits union all
      select 'inserts' union all
      select 'h/i'
     ) x;
```

This may seem complicated, but it is basically only scanning `global_status` once (although that might not be a big deal for a small table).

Comment: perfect answer even I was thinking the same just in few lines not that it requires union as such

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thank you. Super. The `max()` tells me what I needed to know!

Answer (score 1):

this will work:

```
SELECT 'Hits', variable_value 
FROM global_status 
WHERE variable_name = 'QCACHE_HITS'

UNION

SELECT 'Inserts', variable_value 
FROM global_status 
WHERE variable_name = 'QCACHE_INSERTS'

UNION

select 'H/I',(SELECT variable_value 
FROM global_status 
WHERE variable_name = 'QCACHE_HITS')/(SELECT variable_value 
FROM global_status 
WHERE variable_name = 'QCACHE_INSERTS') as variable_value
);
```

Comment: Thank you. There's some error in the SQL and without an explanation of what was happening, I couldn't resolve it. The second answer here helps me. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As Inserts and hits results are different just union and divide the two seperate subqueries as below and get the o/p

Also, Join isnt required coz you dont need an extra column or etc but an extra row data

```
   .... UNION
       Select 'H/I',(SELECT  variable_value 
      FROM global_status 
      WHERE variable_name = 
       'QCACHE_HITS')
       /
    (  SELECT variable_value 
     FROM global_status 
      WHERE variable_name = 
      'QCACHE_INSERTS')
```

Comment: coz explanation of the answer we are giving  to what OP's asking matters